# Which Kotlin metadata version is used in Android Kotlin Compiler

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinc

### Problem

Android tools uses [a custom version of Kotlin Compiler](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:prebuilts/gradle-plugin/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/).

**Is there a way to understand which version of Kotlin metadata this custom compiler uses?**

### Context

1. Lints from Android-tools has a `/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/` dependency with a specific Kotlin metadata somewhere under the hood.
2. Your average Kotlin target uses a *different version* of Kotlin Compiler.
3. As a result Kotlin update in your project, let's say 1.5.30 -> 1.6.0-M1 will lead to a problem:

   ```
   Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
   ```